# PySide 2 компиляция под Андроид

Tags: python

Можно ли приложение pyside скомпилировать под Андроид. Если да, то как

Comment: вот вам для прочтения https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+Android

Answer (score 0):

На просторах интернета нашел статью которая тебе поможет:
https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_for_Android_guide